# Is it safe to abandon a child when moving in with your husband?

Tags: the-sims-3

Frank seduced Pauline, who was dating Hank, and convinced her to dump him. (*Yes, Frank is a d*ck*) Things happened, and Pauline somehow got pregnant ; Frank proposed to her, and they eventually got married.

The thing is, Pauline's child was already born, and Frank wasn't there because you know, being a conductor at the Opera and working 5 hours a day is hard. Hence he discovered the child's name only when Pauline came to live in his house ; he thinks Hank might have chosen the name (Pauline and him were still living together), because it is awful. (*The awful name will not be revealed here, to avoid hurting anyone bearing it.*)

Now Pauline and Frank are living together. Without their child, who stayed with Hank.

### What are the consequences of such a situation ? Will the child hate his parents, will the mother experience a mental breakdown ?

Comment: ...what's the social services number again..? OH. Wait. All good. She's talking about Sims

Comment: @Ben I'm a man, and I will not answer any comment  about why the hell I ask this question. Which title is obviously creepy on purpose :D

Comment: I do apologize, I slipped on that. Honestly thought I said "they"

Comment: No problem, I laughed.

Comment: @Ealhad, don't be a d*ck yourself, take the kid with you.

Comment: @ardaozkal "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request..." Oh, that's a comment already. I didn't ask you to tell me not to do what I have already done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to abandon a child. No consequences at all.

Pauline and Frank are living happily, and have a little girl.

Comment: I am *almost* disappointed.